# Add a git project as submodule without the projects submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've the following projects.
With B and C are meant to be libraries

```
A - B(submodule)

C - B(submodule)
```

Now I want to include project C as git submodule in project A

```
A - B(submodule)
|___C(submodule) - B'(submodule)
```

I want to get rid of the B' submodule because project A can call the build of C specifying that B is on an other location.
Can I make this work while

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
A - B(submodule)
|___C(submodule)
```

Still works?

Comment: Two projects (A and C) can refer to different version of project B. I don't see a way to solve this problem specifically in Git submodules. Instead, you could use package managers (like nuget, composer etc).